# How to combine multiple DataFrame rows into 1 with a column containing list values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
| cat0  | cat1 | cat2 | col_list  | Quantity |
| ----- | ---- | ---- | ----------| -------- |
| alpha | x    | a    | [a,b,c,d] | 4        |
| alpha | y    | a    | [e]       | 1        |
| beta  | z    | a    | [f,g]     | 2        |
| gamma | p    | b    | [h]       | 1        |
| gamma | q    | b    | [I,j,k,l] | 4        |
| phi   | r    | c    | [r,s]     | 2        |
| eita  | s    | c    | [m,n]     | 2        |
```

I want it to transform it based on cat2 column. If they have same value then combine those rows into 1 and merge the rows like this:

```
| cat0       | cat1  | cat2 | col_list        | Quantity |
| ---------- | ----- | ---- | ----------------| -------- |
| alpha,beta | x,y,z | a    | [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] | 7        |
| gamma      | p,q   | b    | [h,I,j,k,l]     | 5        |
| phi,eita   | r,s   | c    | [r,s,m,n]       | 4        |
```

If column have strings values (column: cat0,cat1) join and separate them by a comma. If it has list values (column" col_list) then add those elements into a single list. If it is a int value (column: Quantity), then just add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), with `list`/`','.join`, `sum`, or [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

(df
 .groupby('cat2', as_index=False)
 .agg({'cat0': ','.join, 'cat1': ','.join,
       'col_list': lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)),
       'Quantity': 'sum'
       })
 [df.columns] # reindex like original
)
```

*NB. in place or `chain`, you can also use: `lambda x: [v for l in x for x in l]`*

output:

```
               cat0   cat1 cat2               col_list  Quantity
0  alpha,alpha,beta  x,y,z    a  [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]         7
1       gamma,gamma    p,q    b        [h, I, j, k, l]         5
2          phi,eita    r,s    c           [r, s, m, n]         4
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. I was using groupby.agg only but wasnt able to get the right set of rules. I need to learn to use this better. Very handy. Only question is - can I not avoid cat0 and cat1 from being list? and just have them as string separated by comma

Comment: I tried putting str instead of list but then I get an extra \n with some int values which are indices for those rows

Comment: Of course, you can use `','.join` in place of `list`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) after [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for merging mutiple list and `','.join` for merging  string with comma.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> df.groupby('cat2').agg({'cat0': ','.join, 
                        'cat1': ','.join,
                        'col_list' : lambda x: reduce(lambda y,z : y+z, x),
                        'Quantity' : 'sum'})


cat0          cat1    cat2    col_list         Quantity 
alpha,beta    x,y,z   a       [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]  7
gamma         p,q     b       [h,I,j,k,l]      5
phi,eita      r,s     c       [r,s,m,n]        4
```

Explanation: *(how reduce merge multiple list?)*

```
>>> reduce(lambda y,z : y+z, [['a','b','c','d'], ['e'], ['f','g']])
# y <- (['a','b','c','d'] + ['e'])
# y + ['f','g']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```